# Abline won't appear in R

Tags: r, regression

I have run regression in R, when trying to fit an `abline` to the plot nothing happens, no error message appears.

I've had to log transform the data so I'm wondering if this is the issue? The data is not normally distributed however we have still been asked to perform regression.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
alldata<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)

attach(alldata)

plot(weight.g,wingspan.mm,log="xy")

abline(lm(wingspan.mm~weight.g))

fit1<-lm(wingspan.mm~weight.g)

> summary(fit1)

fit2<-lm(log(wingspan.mm)~log(weight.g))

plot(fit2)

plot(weight.g,wingspan.mm,log="xy")

abline(fit2)

abline(lm(log(wingspan.mm)~log(weight.g)))
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Thanks,
Kate

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput(alldata)`. Also, `file.choose()` is not reproducible, so it's best to pass the file path file to `read.csv()`. Also, linear regression does not assume the data follow a normal distribution (but that's an issue better discussed on crossvalidated).

Answer (score 5):

`abline` won't plot a regression line over a log-transformed plot.

For instance this will only plot the points and not the regression line

```
plot(speed~dist, cars, log="xy")
abline(lm(speed~dist, cars))
```

To get around the problem use the `untf` parameter

```
plot(speed~dist, cars, log="xy")
abline(lm(speed~dist, cars), untf=T)
```

From `?abline`:

> If untf is true, and one or both axes are log-transformed, then a curve is drawn corresponding to a line in original coordinates, otherwise a line is drawn in the transformed coordinate system